# ppm double subscripted array error

Tags: c, arrays, ppm

I'm currently making a program for my school project. It's supposed to read a ppm image and return a gradient as an output. But I'm having a problem with large image such as 420 x 360. It works fine with image below 300 pixels on both side. Could anyone tell me what's wrong with my code? Thx. Oh and it's in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct imageHeader{
    char code[3];
    char startComment;
    char comment[1000];
    int width;
    int height;
    int offset;
} header;

struct imagePixel{
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;
    int total;
};

int main(){
    FILE *image;
    FILE *imageOut;



    image = fopen("sunset.ppm", "rb");
    imageOut = fopen("output.ppm", "wb");

    fseek(image, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fseek(imageOut, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // ********* Get the right Code *************
    fgets(header.code, sizeof(header.code), image);


    if(strcmp(header.code, "P3")){
        puts("Not suitable file format!");
    }

    fputs(header.code, imageOut);
    fputs("\n", imageOut);
    //*********** SKIP THE COMMENT IF EXIST *****************
    header.startComment = fgetc(image);
    if(header.startComment = '#'){
        fgets(header.comment, sizeof(header.comment), image);
    }
    fputs(header.comment, imageOut);

    //**************** Get the Width of the picture ***************
    fscanf(image, "%d", &header.width);
    fprintf(imageOut, "%d ", header.width);

    //**************** Get the Height of the picture **************
    fscanf(image, "%d", &header.height);
    fprintf(imageOut, "%d\n", header.height);


    //***************** Get the offset color of the picture ************
    fscanf(image, "%d", &header.offset);
    fprintf(imageOut, "%d\n", header.offset);

    struct imagePixel *ptrOne;


ptrOne = (struct imagePixel*) malloc(sizeof(ptrOne) * header.height *header.width);

if (ptrOne == NULL){
    printf("Error! Run out of memory!");
    return 1;
}

struct imagePixel number[header.height][header.width];

    //**************read the image*****************
    for(int i = 0; i <= header.height - 1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <= header.width - 1; j++){
            fscanf(image, "%d", &number[i][j].red);
            fscanf(image, "%d", &number[i][j].green);
            fscanf(image, "%d", &number[i][j].blue);
            number[i][j].total = (0.2126 * number[i][j].red) + (0.7152 * number[i][j].green) + (0.0722 * number[i][j].blue);
            //number[i][j].total = (number[i][j].red) + (number[i][j].green) + (number[i][j].blue);
        }
    }


    for(int i = 0; i <= header.height - 1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <= header.width - 1; j++){
            int axisXswap = i;
            int axisYswap = j;

            for(int x = i; x <= header.height - 1; x++){
                for(int y = j; y <= header.width - 1; y++){
                    if(number[x][y].total > number[axisXswap][axisYswap].total){
                        axisXswap = x;
                        axisYswap = y;
                    }
                }
            }

            struct imagePixel temp;

            temp.red = number[i][j].red;
            temp.green = number[i][j].green;
            temp.blue = number[i][j].blue;
            temp.total = number[i][j].total;

            number[i][j].red = number[axisXswap][axisYswap].red;
            number[i][j].green = number[axisXswap][axisYswap].green;
            number[i][j].blue = number[axisXswap][axisYswap].blue;
            number[i][j].total = number[axisXswap][axisYswap].total;

            number[axisXswap][axisYswap].red = temp.red;
            number[axisXswap][axisYswap].green = temp.green;
            number[axisXswap][axisYswap].blue = temp.blue;
            number[axisXswap][axisYswap].total = temp.total;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= header.height-1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <= header.width-1; j++){
            fprintf(imageOut, "%d %d %d\n", number[i][j].red, number[i][j].green, number[i][j].blue);
        }
    }



    fclose(image);
    fclose(imageOut);



}
```

Comment: It seems like your `struct imagePixel number[header.height][header.width]` is (way) too large to allocate on the stack, i.e., as a local variable. Use `malloc` to allocate it in the global memory heap.

Comment: Let's check the numbers - struct imagePixel will be 16 bytes (with 32-bit ints), so 16*420*360 = 2.4MB.  Windows will limit the stack to 1MB, so that would explain the problem. (it would help if you said what platform you are using)

There is a malloc in the code, but it isn't correct - you need to take the return value from malloc and use it as a pointer to the block of memory.

Comment: @Bryan: very good -- I got tired after reading the first half. The notes are all there, but not yet in the right order.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now I know what the problem is! By the way, is there any method to reduce such memory? I think 2.4MB it's too big for a simple program like this.

Comment: I changed my malloc. Am I using it correctly? I took an example from a website.

Comment: You will want to use `struct ImagePixel **` because it's two-dimensional.

Comment: So, ptrOne = (struct imagePixel **) malloc(sizeof(ptrOne) * header.height * header.width);?

Comment: btw, how do you make that box around a code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of allocating on the stack you should use the heap:

```
struct imagePixel **number; // two dimensional array of pixels

// allocate rows
number = malloc(sizeof(struct imagePixel *) * header.height);

for (i = 0; i < header.height; ++i) {
    // allocate columns for each row
    number[0] = malloc(sizeof(struct imagePixel) * header.width);
}

// do free() in reverse as above
```

Comment: Thanks! I think it did it with the malloc thing. But then my program stops responding. Is it because I used subscript for the number? e.g. number[i][j]?

Comment: @user3548468 Yeah, made a mistake by doing a single allocation where you really need one allocation for the rows and then for each row another allocation.